# 'DateTime' has no len() occurred, with Odoo and Zapier integration

Tags: odoo, zapier

I am trying to integrate Zapier and Odoo. For the most part all integrations work, however when I attempt to use Stock Move module I am getting the error,

```
Fault (code object of type 'DateTime' has no len()) occurred. Message: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

[Zapier Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18vWF.png)

I have a suspicion it is the way I am entering the date. I have tried multiple times, with different format but with no luck.

Comment: It depends on how the date is used in your code.Please add the next lines of the above log?

Comment: There is no code, please see the picture above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug in zapier. Confirmed with their team, no known solution at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Check-in your code where you try to search the result Like,

result = self.env['obj.obj'].search([('date_field', '=', now.date())]) someting like So try to convert into str formation str(now.date())

The reported issue only occurs where the proper value is not stored [for that check the python date type formation use and applied with same.]or either you can try to search with these things.

Hope this may help you.

Thanks